# How can I redirect the user in my website after his purchase in php file?

Tags: php

How can I redirect the user in my website after his purchase in my  `php` file?

Comment: How can I fix this dongle?

Comment: header("Location:yourpage.php"); TADAH!

Comment: But the user requests for purchase  to the bank server and not to my server.

Comment: Is Harry Potter back? I mean What do we have? Code? Errors? Anything?

Comment: The reason why you're getting downvotes is because this post is not very specific.  Are you running code and getting errors?  Are you looking for what the overarching logic of this step would be?  What does the code around the relevant location look like?

Comment: No, My question is that the structure of `php` language is : first a request from user and then a response from server. But in the  purchase operation the user requests to server bank and not to my server?

Comment: If you are integrated with an eCommerce API its almost guaranteed they will provide you with a way to pass around a return url.  You will need to read the documentation.

Comment: Hey friends ,Try to understand his problem and start down voting.Why do you people doing like this.He might be a fresher and don't discourage him.  @android don't get worried,You should ask a question with sufficient  details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for a client-side redirect or server-side. But here's both

## Server-side PHP redirect

To redirect people via PHP, you can use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Just make sure there is no HTML output before you call `header()`, and that you use either `exit()` or `die()` (they're the same) to stop the script from continuing to execute.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

## Client-side JS redirect

You can use `window.location.replace()` for this pretty easily

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://example.com");
```

## Client-side meta redirect

You can also redirect people with the `meta refresh` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

This will work when users have JS disabled.

---

I would caution against using client-side redirects however, as they look very unprofessional and in the case of the JS redirect, aren't even guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for helping him @Tim